Django command doesn't apply changes when raising an exception
I created a django command to remove about 100.000 entries in our database, however we tested it and noticed that when the command is terminated or otherwise raises an exception, the delete() is not applied.
For example the command is at 100 of the 100.000 and we terminate the command, all entries are still there and the 100 that should be gone are still there.
Does anybody know why this happens and if this behaviour can be disabled. I know this can be dangerous, but we need it.
I tried to look at the implementation, but I cannot figure it out.

It's probably running the bulk delete in a transaction, so that if you exit via an unhandled exception, the transaction is rolled back. This is normally what one wants, but it has be be explicitly coded (your programmer, or in some module you are using). Post the code if you need more help.

Well what error does it raise? Django's deletions are often not cheap, because Django itself runs the on_delete triggers, this means that Django sometimes does an awful amount of work to remove a few records, whereas triggers at the database could have done it more efficiently.

Actually Django’s default behaviour is to run in autocommit mode unless a transaction is active. In your case, a transaction is active.
Django implicitly uses transactions during operations that require multiple queries, especially delete() and update() queries to guarantee the integrity of these ORM operations.
So what you are experiencing is a transaction rollback due to the termination of the delete() query.
While you cannot disable the implicit use of transactions for a specific query, you can disable Django’s use of transactions on a database server completely.

settings.py
DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "AUTOCOMMIT": False,
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.•••",
        #•••Rest of code•••,
    }
}

Note that this is not a silver bullet and this is a strange requirement. It is not portable and you will be at the mercy of the underlying database library and whatever its behaviour is unless you want to manipulate that too.
Everybody needs transaction rollback features when something goes wrong (for example; a network failure during a payment procedure). The reason why you don’t want it is what I call strange.

Better to change the code? Although normally regarded as inefficient: for junk in queryset: junk.delete() so there's no overall transaction.

With "AUTOCOMMIT": False, Django stops using transactions and the database now does it the usual way - the database way. Postgres uses transactions though.

Yes, if that's what you want for the entire Django project rather than one minor piece of it.

You cannot disable the implicit use of transactions for a specific query so it is all or nothing. I’ve raised an issue on the project repo. What’s left on my end is completing the pull request I’m working on. Hopefully it will be considered. A decorator like @autocommit maybe?

Thank you for your answers. The software is written a long time ago by someone else and it has a couple of flaws. However I think I'm going to delete those users in smaller batches, which would solve the problem in a different way. Again thanks everybody!
